# Selenium-python can't find elements with certain name attributes

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium-python 2.46.1, and input elements with names like `chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title` don't come up with the following code:

*input element is :*

```
<input id="id_chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title" maxlength="255" name="chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title" type="text" />
```

I have tried:

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input')
        for ii in ids:
            print ii.get_attribute('name')    # id name as string
```

or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title")
```

though

`'assert "chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title" in self.driver.page_source'` is fine

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In a webpage(even on simple one) there could be many input tags and you don't want to loop through all of them to find one attribute. Since the html tag contains id attribute(and I assume that is unique) you can easily find the element and check for any attribute there.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title')
name = element.get_attribute('name')
assert "chunk_items-__prefix__-chunk_title" in name
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I realise looping through is not the way normally, I should have explained better that this was just to see if they showed up.

I've found out now that some Javascript is causing issues, so it wasn't an issue with Selenium after all.

Thanks anyway.